# Is $[\mathbb{Z}/1][x]$ not the zero ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

I am having trouble finding much information about $[\mathbb{Z}/1][x]$ other than a short Wikipedia exerpt.

I had a problem on my last homework assignment, where I had to determine for which integers $n$ does a specific polynomial divide another polynomial in $[\mathbb{Z}/n][x]$. I figured that $[\mathbb{Z}/1][x]$ would indeed be the zero ring, since all numbers are congruent modulo $1$ (and all integers evaluate to $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/1$?). So I thought that no polynomial could divide another in the ring $[\mathbb{Z}/1][x]$...

Is this not the correct logic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say with the division part of your post, but yes: $(\mathbb Z / 1)[x]$ is the trivial ring.

Comment: We were given two polynomials and had to determine for which $n$ that the one polynomial would divide the other in $(\mathbb{Z}/n)[x]$. One student made the argument that the one polynomial would divide the other in $(\mathbb{Z}/1)[x]$, but I did not think that it would because $0$ cannot divide $0$... But thank you for your response

Comment: Well, zero divides zero: By definition $a$ divides $b$ iff there is some $c$ such that $a \cdot c = b$. Since $0 \cdot 0 = 0$, we always have (in any ring) that $0$ divides $0$.

Comment: Ahh, see I thought that it worked by definition... but in my entire life I have always been told that zero cannot divide zero so I figured it would still hold in a ring of integers :( So I must always stick to my definitions...

Comment: If $R$ is the trivial ring, then every polynomial in $R[x]$ has only zero as coefficients.